# Java API Designing issue in creating own API

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, api-design

I am working on a project that includes communication between computer application and embedded devices over serial port in Master-Slave mode.

The application will serve as Master to multiple embedded devices working as Slaves.

The communication part is almost complete. But now, I am refactoring it as an API.
So, it can be used over multiple projects or by many developers with very less configurations.

I am not very good in API design, even it's the first time, I am creating an API.

Now, I am stuck on following issue:
Consider this scenario:

```
/*
 * API Part
 */
public abstract class AbstractSlave {

  // Some fields, constructor and other methods.

  final void handle(Request request, Response response) {
    // Some operations before starting worker thread.

    SlaveWorker worker = new SlaveWorker(request, response);
    worker.start();
  }

}

public class SlaveWorker extends Thread {

  // Constructor

  @Override
  public final void run() {
    work(request, response);
  }

  public void work(Request request, Response response) {

  }

}
```

`AbstractSlave` class starts a worker thread to work upon the request and response, so that long-running operations cannot cause the loss of upcoming responses from slaves.

Now, here is the "API usage part":

```
/*
 * API Usage Part
 */
public class Slave extends AbstractSlave {

  // Constructor

}

public class MyWorker extends SlaveWorker {

  // Constructor

  @Override
  public void work(Request request, Response response) {
    super.work(request, response);

    // My work to be done upon request and response.
  }

}
```

But as we can see, `AbstractSlave` creates `SlaveWorker` instances.
So, `SlaveWorker` `work()` method will be called, instead of `MyWorker`.

How to make `AbstractSlave` class to call `MyWorker` `work()` method?

***NOTE:***

- As it's an API design, `AbstractSlave` would not know, there is a `MyWorker` class. So, `MyWorker` instances cannot be created directly in place of `SlaveWorker`.
- `handle()` method of `AbstractSlave` can/meant not be overridden, because there are some operations, that need to be performed before starting worker thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key point would be to let the client of your API create the instance of `SlaveWorker` (or any subclass), so that he can customize the `work()` method.

IMO you should provide a `Worker` interface in your API (interface is less constraining than an abstract class):

```
public interface Worker {
    public void work(Request request, Response response);
}
```

And `AbstractSlave`'s method should be like:

```
public abstract class AbstractSlave {

    private final Worker worker;

    public AbstractSlave(Worker worker) {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    final void handle(final Request request, final Response response)
        // Some operations before starting worker thread.

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                worker.work(request, response);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: In your handle method design, worker instance is being passed. But again handle is being called from inside the API. How 'MyWorker' instance could be passed then?

Comment: As, from your second edit. I think the same way. Letting the client to provide the instance. But, what would be the best way! I am thinking to create a abstract getSlaveWorker() method in AbstractSlave class. Do you think, it's right approach?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know `handle()` was called from the API. Then you should probably have a `worker` field in your `AbstractSlave` that is set in the constructor, or indeed an abstract getter retrieving it.

Comment: worker field in AbstractSlave would not work i think. As, I need to create a new instance everytime, when handle() is invoked.

Comment: Why would you need new instances everytime? The way request and response are handled changes each time?

Comment: In my design, SlaveWorker is a subclass of Thread. So, I will need, new instances for starting new threads. Wouldn't your design require new instances of Worker?

Comment: No, my design wouldn't need new instances, because a new Thread is created, but that all threads use the same instance of Worker.

Comment: Finally, I used this approach. But instead of using Worker as field, I am getting Worker instance by an abstract getWorker() method. I was just cautious for thread-safety. BTW, when implemented this design, all other problems solved very easily, like an extremely simple puzzle, every piece falling into its own space itself. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome ;) However, using an abstract method will not guarantee thread safety, as most likely the classes implementing it will return the same object anyway, so it won't be much different from a final field except that the Worker *could* be different from one call to another.

Comment: Yes, currently, I am returning new Worker instances from getWorker() method.
But, API user can avoid returning new instances.
Can there be a way to force them, to create new instances every time?

Comment: IMO, there is no point in doing so. Using the same Worker is better in terms of performance, let them do it if they want to, maybe they will need to (if they want to count something for instance. They shouldn't be tempted by adding state to their worker without considering thread safety themselves anyway, but you can warn them that their code should be reentrant.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this, but one way is to add a `configureJob` method to your `AbstractSlave`and use this to tell your `AbstractSlave` class about `MyWorker`.

```
public class SlaveManager {
   private Class workerClass = SlaveWorker.class;

   public void configureJob(Class clazz){
      workerClass = clazz;
   }

   final void handle(Request request, Response response) {
      // Some operations before starting worker thread.

      Worker worker = workerClass.newInstance();
      worker.start(request, response);
   }
}

public interface Worker {
   public void work(Request request, Response response);
}
```

In your `main` method, just call `SlaveManager::configureJob(MyWorker.class)` before you call `SlaveManager::handle()`.

Now, I've kept things simple above by using `Object.newInstance()` to create the `Worker`, but this is not a recommended general practice. It's more customary to use a `WorkerFactory` instead, but I didn't want to introduce a new class and a new design pattern in case you were unfamiliar with the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Comment: In your design, `Worker` is no longer a `Thread`, you can't call `start()`. Also, I'm not sure the OP wants the client to be able to change the behaviour of `work()` at any time, but that's for @Akshat to tell ;)

Comment: I am familiar with Factory Pattern. I also thought about using it. But since, there will be only one type of Worker. So, I guess, factory pattern is not worth it here.

Comment: I left out the Worker implements Thread/Runnable part, as that wasn't relevant to the primary difficulty the OP was having -- the knowledge responsibility issues of the various participants.